# Add Condition to Rest Assured

Tags: java, rest, if-statement, conditional-statements, rest-assured

I want to add a condition to Rest Assured. For example, if I have input 1, the request should be checked for condition 1, but if I do not have input 1, condition 1 should not be checked. Of course I could do the if outside the request and just not add the check, but I have several cases like this this is a lot of unnecessary code. Is there any way I can save code using an inline if?

```
if (condition1){
      response =
                given().
                        spec(spec).
                        body(data).
                        when().
                        post("/test").
                        then().
                        assertThat(). 
                        statusCode(201).
                        body("id", 1).
                        extract().
                        response();
} else {
      response =
                given().
                        spec(spec).
                        body(data).
                        when().
                        post("/test").
                        then().
                        assertThat(). 
                        statusCode(201).

                        //DONT DO THE CHECK

                        extract().
                        response();
}
```

Is there a way to do that in one line? Something like this:

```
response =
                    given().
                            spec(spec).
                            body(data).
                            when().
                            post("/test").
                            then().
                            assertThat(). 
                            statusCode(201).

                            if condition do this body("id", 1) otherwise dont do anything

                            extract().
                            response();
```

Comment: You found a solution for that in the meantime?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
ValidatableResponse validatableResponse =
           given()
                .spec(spec)
                .body(data)
                .when()
                .post(endpoint)
                .then()
                .spec(responseSpec)
                .assertThat();

if (condition) {
    validatableResponse.body("id", 1)
}

Response response = validatableResponse.extract().response();
```